# Where does Jetpack store markdown?

Tags: plugin-jetpack, markdown

I use the [Jetpack markdown](https://jetpack.com/support/markdown/) feature.

If I open a previously markdown written post, it will open as a markdown written post. However if I export my site to XML with the official export plugin, it will be exported as HTML.

So my question is does Jetpack store the posts markdown anywhere? Or does it actually convert the post back from HTML to Markdown every time I open a post to edit it?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer after exploring the MySQL database and finding the right field.

Here is an answer from Ryan Cowles at the Jetpack staff:

> The HTML version of your post is stored in `post_content` and the Markdown version is stored in `post_content_filtered`. You can see how it’s stored [here](https://cloudup.com/cF41W5LaBCY).
>
> Specifics aside, if you write a post with Markdown enabled and then disable the module (or Jetpack entirely) the post will still display properly.